# Translate custom labels fields in function.php file of my theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, translation, custom-fields

With the help from the community, I have succeeded to create, save and print the labels and their values to the single product page.

I can also translate the input values into different languages using **Polylang**, but translating the custom labels (Conditions and Brands) is extremely hard.

Anyone out there can help me with these issues?

I tried to use **Polylang**, **Saywhat**...with no success!

Here is the code:

```
// Enabling and Displaying Fields in backend
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group">';
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( // Text Field type
        'id'          => '_conditions', 
        'label'       => __( 'Conditions', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder' => 'i.e: brand-new; refurbished; defected...',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter the conditions of the products here.', 'woocommerce' ) 
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( // Text Field type
        'id'          => '_brands',
        'label'       => __( 'Brands', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder' => 'i.e: Lacoste; Hugo Boss...etc',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter names of the Brands of the products if any.', 'woocommerce' ) 
    ));
    echo '</div>'; // Closing </div> tag HERE
}

// Save Fields values to database when submitted (Backend)
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_save_custom_general_fields' );
function woo_save_custom_general_fields( $post_id ){

    // Saving "Conditions" field key/value
    $conditions_field = $_POST['_conditions'];
    if( !empty( $conditions_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_conditions', esc_attr( $conditions_field ) );

    // Saving "Brands" field key/value
    $brands_field = $_POST['_brands'];
    if( !empty( $brands_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_brands', esc_attr( $brands_field ) );
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woo_display_custom_general_fields_values', 20);
function woo_display_custom_general_fields_values() {
    global $product;

    echo '<p class="custom-conditions">Conditions: ' . get_post_meta( $product->id, '_conditions', true ) . '</p>';
    echo '<p class="custom-brands">Brands: ' . get_post_meta( $product->id, '_brands', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

And here a screenshot:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I tried loco but it didn't help. To be honest, I didn't try it hard. I am still looking for solution within Polylang because I found Polylang really great!

Comment: Polylang will not really work completely with WooCommerce… You will see that, may be too late, when your project will be mostly finished (In this case removing Polylang and setting all for another plugin is going to be a long and complex process)… I tell you that by experience and I use everywhere WPML without no problems. So may be is good for you to think about it now.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, i changed to WPML, the process is a bit complicating but it seems more stable and easier to work with than Polylang. What a pity for Polylang though!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should change the gettex domain name from **`'woocommerce'`** to the domain name of your theme (or something more custom), as it doesn't make part of woocommerce code, and it's located in your active theme.

**1) the Free alternative:**

> Then as it's not really content that you are trying to translate, but some peaces of code located in the **`function.php`** file of your active child theme (or active theme), you should use a specialized free plugin as [**Loco Translate**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) that will provides in-browser editing of WordPress translation files.

Loco Translate, also provides localization tools for developers, such as extracting strings and generating templates.

Loco Translate features include:

- Built-in translation editor within WordPress admin
- Create and update language files directly in your theme or plugin
- Extraction of translatable strings from your source code
- Native MO file compilation without the need for Gettext on your system
- Support for PO features including comments, references and plural forms
- PO source view with clickable source code references
- Protected language directory for saving custom translations
- Configurable PO file backups
- Built-in WordPress locale codes

---

**2) The commercial complete way (completely compatible with WooCommerce):**

The most complete commercial alternative is [**WPML**](https://wpml.org) plugin, that will also handle perfectly and more easily WooCommerce custom localisation and translations content for multilingual web sites. The other free optional plugins are incomplete for WooCommerce and much more difficult to get them work totally well.

> So If you are planing to publish a multilingual website, think about it.